# Loop through worksheets except summary and copy paste data sequentially, getting 438 error while pasting? Code attached below

Tags: excel, vba, loops

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Integer
    a = Application.Worksheets.Count - 1

    For i = 1 To a

        Worksheets(i).Activate


        Worksheets(i).Cells(10, 4).Select
        Worksheets(i).Cells(10, 4).Copy
        Worksheets("Summary").Activate
        Worksheets("Summary").Cells(1, 2).Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You may be missing a reference to the Workbook, take  look at this link...  Dim wkbDest As Workbook
  Dim TP As Worksheet
  
  Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Table Plan for Cameron.xlsm")    http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?48304-Run-time-error-438-Object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method

Answer (score 0):

the issue is in :

```
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(1, 2).Selection
```

since `Selection` isn't a member of the `Range` object

In the style of your original code you would just correct it to:

```
Worksheets("Summary").Cells(1, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

But you must avoid all that `Selection` and `Activate`, and just use fully qualifed ranges
:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Long
    a = Application.Worksheets.Count - 1

    For i = 1 To a
        Worksheets(i).Cells(10, 4).Copy Worksheets("Summary").Cells(1, 2)
    Next
End Sub
```

BTW with your code you keep writing in `Worksheets("Summary").Cells(1, 2)` cell, so that it'll eventually end with the value of D10 cell of last worksheet looped

While if you want to keep filling down `Worksheets("Summary")` column 2, use this code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim a As Long

    a = Application.Worksheets.Count - 1    
    For i = 1 To a
         Worksheets(i).Cells(10, 4).Copy Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub
```